# cross compile boost libraries from windows to linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost, build

I am trying to compile all of boost libraries from my Windows machine to Linux (ARM Cortex A9). I downloaded boost 1.64 and ran bootstrap, after that i edited project-config.jam so it looks like the following:

> import option ;
>
> using gcc : arm : "C:\Program Files (x86)\...\arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" ;
>
> option.set keep-going : false ;

and then on the command prompt i entered

> b2 install toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux --build-type=complete --prefix=C:\a

and it seems like nothing is happening, or b2 is searching for something it can't find so it gets stuck.

command prompt after I entered the command above:
[image: command prompt after I entered the command above]

Note that I have never done this before so maybe I am doing some rookie mistake.

If anyone knows why nothing is happening when i run b2 or how i can build boost libraries for linux in some other way I'd love some assistance.

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply compile natively on a Linux machine (or VM)? With a proper CI build setup it should just be a matter of adding another build slave.

Comment: I could try that, but it seems like an overkill (I need to install VM first). I know there has to be some way doing that with the right configuration/commands, so it seems like the preferable option.

Comment: "overkill (I need to install VM first)" - in my experience that would be a 15min job.

Comment: ok, I'm going to try that but I would like also to know how to do it while staying on windows

Comment: No need to compile natively on a linux machine,  A precompiled package is readily available directly from dnf, apt-get or the likes.

Comment: im going to check that out, thanks

Comment: Usually those little ARM devices (like RaspberryPi) run a fully-fledged Linux distribution with package management.  Just install the Boost libraries from the repository.